# displaying restaurants nearby a user location within 5 kilometers in Django

Tags: django

Good morning Everyone,

I would like to display restaurants within 5 kilometers in using  google maps api , How could I do it?

I have done the latitudes and longitudes calculs with haversine. But i don't know how rendering the result in django.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need django here, what you're looking for can be done using [Google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) and a map provider (Like Google maps) or Openstreetmap through [Leaflet JS](https://leafletjs.com/).

This is all mostly done with Javascript in a template.

There is a Python version of Leaflet, named [folium](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/), if you really want to stick with Python. Not sure you can do everything, as I'm not that familiar with it.